# Py4JJavaError when connecting to Cassandra from Spark

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

How can I connect to Cassandra from Spark with iPython?

I have followed the code from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py) and modified it,

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "C:\Apache\spark-1.4.1"

# Append pyspark to Python Path
sys.path.append("C:\Apache\spark-1.4.1\python")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

host = 'localhost'
keyspace = 'demo'
cf = 'users'
sc = SparkContext(appName="CassandraInputFormat")

conf = {"cassandra.input.thrift.address": host,
        "cassandra.input.thrift.port": "9160",
        "cassandra.input.keyspace": keyspace,
        "cassandra.input.columnfamily": cf,
        "cassandra.input.partitioner.class": "Murmur3Partitioner",
        "cassandra.input.page.row.size": "3"}

cass_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat",
        "java.util.Map",
        "java.util.Map",
        keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.CassandraCQLKeyConverter",
        valueConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.CassandraCQLValueConverter",
        conf=conf)

output = cass_rdd.collect()
```

When I run it from the ipython notebook, I get this error below,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-15-458818fce35c> in <module>()
     29         keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.CassandraCQLKeyConverter",
     30         valueConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.CassandraCQLValueConverter",
---> 31         conf=conf)
     32 
     33 output = cass_rdd.collect()

C:\Apache\spark-1.4.1\python\pyspark\context.pyc in newAPIHadoopRDD(self, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter, conf, batchSize)
    599         jrdd = self._jvm.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(self._jsc, inputFormatClass, keyClass,
    600                                                    valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter,
--> 601                                                    jconf, batchSize)
    602         return RDD(jrdd, self)
    603 

C:\Users\lauthiamkok\inotebook\lib\site-packages\py4j-0.9-py2.7.egg\py4j\java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Users\lauthiamkok\inotebook\lib\site-packages\py4j-0.9-py2.7.egg\py4j\protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(
```

And more...

```
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD. :
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:179)    at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDDFromClassNames(PythonRDD.scala:520)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:503)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas what have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the cause: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, which means the jar isn't found & the path to the jar isn't getting set correctly.

Can you run the examples from the command line?

```
Run with example jar:
    ./bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/example/jar \
    /path/to/examples/cassandra_inputformat.py <host> <keyspace> <cf>
```